# Apply Auto DDL Configuration to Dynamically Loaded DataSources in Multi-Tenant Spring Data JPA App

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I am prototyping a multi-tenant spring boot app with spring data JPA. The multi-tenant strategy I'm employing is DATABASE, per [the hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy-separate-database). The tenant databases are not known at bootup time, so I must lookup the database connection details from a service and dynamically initialize a `DataSource` whenever I'm passed a tenant identifier I haven't seen before. Just for the purposes of bootup configuration (when a tenant identifier is not available), I create a "default" data source from the first tenant that happens to be returned by the lookup service, so its schema and vendor are identical to the other tenants.

For the most part, I have this working, in that my `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` implementation locates the correct `DataSource` for the requested tenant at runtime, creating new data sources when appropriate. The problem is that the only data source initialized with the Spring/Hibernate auto DDL configuration is the default data source mentioned above. So in my development environment, where I'm creating embedded databases and have `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`, the default tenant works as expected by creating the expected schema, but all other tenants fail with this message:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "my_table" not found (this database is empty);

In production, I'm not planning to auto-populate the schema from my application code, but I would like to at least validate it with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate`.

I've seen plenty of examples of how to initialize data sources dynamically, but I've only seen examples where the schema is already in place. How do I take advantage of the Spring/Hibernate auto DDL generation/validation?

Here are some classes I've implemented to get multi-tenant working:

General configuration for multi-tenancy:

```
@Configuration
public class TenantConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer, HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    private final String tenantHeader;
    private final TenantIdentifierResolver tenantIdentifierResolver;
    private final TenantConnectionProvider tenantConnectionProvider;

    public TenantConfiguration(final String tenantHeader,
            final TenantIdentifierResolver tenantIdentifierResolver,
            final TenantConnectionProvider tenantConnectionProvider) {
        this.tenantHeader = Objects.requireNonNull(String tenantHeader);
        this.tenantIdentifierResolver = Objects.requireNonNull(tenantIdentifierResolver);
        this.tenantConnectionProvider = Objects.requireNonNull(tenantConnectionProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new TenantRequestInterceptor(tenantHeader));
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
        hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, tenantIdentifierResolver);
        hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, tenantConnectionProvider);
    }

}
```

Implementation of `MultiTenantConnectionProvider`

```
@Component
public class TenantConnectionProvider extends AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl {

    private final DataSourceProperties dsProperties;
    private final TenantClient tenantClient;  // The "lookup service" mentioned earlier
    private final TenantIdentifierResolver tenantIdResolver;
    private final ConcurrentMap<String, DataSource> tenantDataSources;

    public TenantConnectionProvider(final DataSourceProperties dsProperties, final TenantClient tenantClient,
            final TenantIdentifierResolver tenantIdResolver) {
        this.dsProperties = Objects.requireNonNull(dsProperties);
        this.tenantClient = Objects.requireNonNull(tenantClient);
        this.tenantIdResolver = Objects.requireNonNull(tenantIdResolver);
        this.tenantDataSources = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected DataSource selectAnyDataSource() {
        return selectDataSource(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected DataSource selectDataSource(final String tenantId) {
        final String resolvedId = (tenantId == null) ? tenantIdResolver.resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() : tenantId;
        return tenantDataSources.computeIfAbsent(resolvedId, v -> createDataSource(resolvedId));
    }

    private DataSource createDataSource(final String tenantId) {
        final TenantDatabase database = tenantClient.getTenantDatabase(tenantId);
        return dsProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .url(String.format("jdbc:h2:mem:tenant-%s", tenantId)) // TODO: replace hard-coded development URLs
                .username(database.getUser())
                .password(database.getPassword())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Development application properties

```
spring.datasource.name=Multi-Tenant Data Source
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.jpa.database=H2
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do auto DDL for the dynamic data sources, but I feel it's more of a hack than a solution. I updated `TenantConnectionProvider.createDataSource()` by creating a temporary Entity Manager Factory for each new data source, and disposing the factory when done:

```
    private DataSource createDataSource(final String tenantId) {
        final TenantDatabase database = tenantClient.getTenantDatabase(tenantId);
        final DataSource dataSource = dsProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .url(resolveUrl(database))
                .username(database.getUser())
                .password(database.getPassword())
                .build();

        if (!tenantDataSources.isEmpty()) {
            // HACK to trigger auto DDL generation.
            //
            // Only the first datasource is initialized by the spring data auto
            // DDL configuration. For all subsequently initialized data sources,
            // Create (and destroy!) a temporary entity manager factory to
            // initialize/validate the datasource DDL.
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            emfBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
            emfBean.setPackagesToScan("com.myapp");
            emfBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
            emfBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
            emfBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties.getProperties());
            emfBean.afterPropertiesSet();  // <--- This triggers the auto DDL
            emfBean.destroy();
        }

        return dataSource;
    }

    private String resolveUrl(final TenantDatabase database) {
        String url = dsProperties.getUrl();
        if (database.getServerName() != null) {
            url = url.replace("{{hostName}}", database.getServerName());
        }
        if (database.getDatabaseName() != null) {
            url = url.replace("{{dbName}}", database.getDatabaseName());
        }
        if (database.getTenantId() != null) {
            url = url.replace("{{tenantId}}", database.getTenantId());
        }
        return url;
    }
```

The `jpaProperties (JpaProperties.class)` reference is now injected into the connection provider component as a constructor parameter. With the following properties, my temporary entity manager factory has approximately the same settings as the application instance initialized by the JPA configuration:

```
spring.datasource.name=Multi-Tenant Data Source
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/.bridge/{{tenantId}}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.jpa.database=H2
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
```